# EoF and CTRL + D

Tags: c

**1st Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int c = 0;
    
    printf("Please enter a character (ctrl-D to exit):");
    
    while(c != 4){ //(4 is the ASCII value for ctrl-D)
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    printf("CTRL + D pressed..");
    
    printf("The value of EOF is: %d", EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on Ubuntu:

- When the input is 'a' followed by ENTER, the output is 'a'. The output is as expected.
- When the input is 'abcd^D', the output is 'abcd'. The output is as expected. CTRL + D is detected as the end of the input.
- When the input is '^D', the output is the continuous display of strange character. I need to enter CTRL + C to stop. Not sure what is happening here.

Output on Windows:

- When the input is 'a' followed by ENTER, the output is 'a'. The output is as expected.
- When the input is 'abcd^D' followed by ENTER, the output is 'abcdCTRL + D pressed.. The value of EOF is: -1'. CTRL + D is just a character in Windows. SO, need to press ENTER.
- When the input is '^D' followed by ENTER, the output is 'CTRL + D pressed.. The value of EOF is: -1'. The output is expected with reason same as above.

**2nd Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int c;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        putchar( c );
    }
    printf("CTRL + D pressed..");
    
    printf("The value of EOF is: %d", EOF);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output on Ubuntu:

- When the input is 'a' followed by ENTER, the output is 'a'.
- When the input is 'abcd^D', the output is 'abcd'.
- When the input is '^D', the output is 'CTRL + D pressed.. The value of EOF is: -1'.

Output on Windows:

- When the input is 'a' followed by ENTER, the output is 'a'.
- When the input is 'abcd^D' followed by ENTER, the output is 'abcd' followed by strange character.
- When the input is '^D' followed by ENTER, the output is a strange character.
- When the input is '^Z' followed by ENTER, the output is 'CTRL + D pressed.. The value of EOF is: -1'. The output is as expected. CTRL + Z in Windows is equivalent to CTRL + D in Ubuntu.

Thanks
Joi

My trouble to understand is why on the 1st program, on entering 'CTRL + D', the program displays infinite characters?
On the 1st program (on Ubuntu, 2nd output), CTRL + D is interpreted as the end of the input, just like in shell. But on the 3rd output, it just does not recognize it.

On the 2nd program (On Ubuntu, 2nd and 3rd output), CTRL + D is interpreted as the EOF.

If we look at both values, I am not able to understand what exactly if the value of CTRL + D? Is it 4 (ASCII value of CTRL +D) or -1?

Any other conclusion would be very welcome too.

Comment: You are wondering why different operating systems work differently?

Comment: `while(c != 4)` ==> `while(c != EOF)`. Stream input is line-oriented and buffered, and with Windows, the `Ctrl-Z` needs to be preceded and followed by `Enter`. The value `EOF` isn't a character, but a *flag*. This is a reason why the function returns an `int` value, not a `char` value – so that `EOF` can be distinguished from any value of character read from the file. So, on Linux, `Ctrl-D` pressed returns `EOF` not `4`.

Comment: *Output on Windows: When the input is `abcd^D` followed by `ENTER`, the output is `abcd` followed by strange character.* That is because `4` is a non-printing character, and the terminal provides a smiley face or a card suit, whatever. It would be more revealing if instead of `putchar(c);` you use `printf("%d\n", c);`

Comment: You're missing the fact that end-of-file is a state. Pressing ctrl-D puts the input stream into the end-of-file state, and it remains in that state forever. When an input stream is in the end-of-file state, calling `getchar` will return `EOF`, which is usually defined as -1.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thank you for your answer. I used printf() as you suggested and that was more revealing. But why is this strange character being printed continuously? Why not just one time, since -1 is not equal to 4, the condition has become true and it should ask for another input. Why is getchar reading the same CTRL + D from the buffer on each getch() and displaying it? What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first program exits the `while` loop only when the character with code 4 is entered. This did not occur in any of your Ubuntu examples. In Unix systems, the default terminal behavior when <kbd>Control-D</kbd> is pressed is to send the pending data to the attached process. It does not send a “Control-D” character.

When the program starts, it enters the `while` loop and evaluates `putchar(c)`. At that point, `c` is zero, so the program sends a null character to standard output, which does not display anything. Then the program proceeds to evaluate `c = getchar()`.

When you pressed the <kbd>A</kbd> key, an “a” character was generated. When you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a newline character was generated, and both characters were sent to the process running your program. The program completed the `getchar`, returning the code for “a” (likely 91). The `while` loop looped, and wrote the character with `putchar`, displaying “a”. Then the program evaluated `getchar` again, got the code for the newline character, and wrote it with `putchar`, advancing the display in your terminal. Then your program executed `getchar` again, at which point it waited for more input. You must have terminated the process somehow, possibly by pressing <kbd>Control-C</kbd>.

When you pressed <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>D</kbd>, the characters “a”, “b”, “c”, and “d” were generated and held in the terminal’s buffer. When you then pressed <kbd>Control-D</kbd>, those characters were sent to the process, which printed them. Again, you must have terminated the process somehow.

When you pressed <kbd>Control-D</kbd> as the first thing after running the program, the contents of the terminal buffer were sent to the process. However, the buffer was empty, so the process was notified that zero characters had been read. When the stream software in the standard C library on Ubuntu (and Unix systems generally) receives zero characters for an attempted read operation, it reports it to the program as an end-of-file. Thus, `getchar` returned `EOF`. The value of `EOF` is not a character value, so it is not 4, so the `while` loop continued. It executed `putchar(c)`. `putchar` converts the value passed to it to `unsigned char` and prints the resulting character. That caused the “strange character” you saw. Then the program executed `c = getchar();` again. However, once the stream is in an end-of-file state, it remains in that state until the program resets it (which you can do with `clearerr(stdin)`). While in that state, `getchar` returns `EOF`. So your program loops forever, getting `EOF` from `getchar` and printing it with `putchar`.

On Windows, pressing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> generates a “Control-D” character with code 4, so that results in your program exiting the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful and detailed explanation.